# JavaFX: OutOfMemory because of VirtualFlow in TableView

Tags: java, javafx, out-of-memory

**The situation:**

- Our application crashed because with an OutOfMemory exception
- The application consists of a main window with a TableView
- There are a few thousand rows added over the course of a working day
- This window is not closed during the whole working day

**What we know:**

When analysing the heap dump you see that VirtualFlow (part of a TableView) uses a lot of memory:

[Memory usage VirtualFlow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVV97.png)

**Details**

The VirtualFlow has an internal Array called privateCells. When reading the source code it seems that this array is never cleared (e. g. always holds a reference to TableRow's).
A TableRow can use hundreds of KB of memory (depending on the number of columns). Therefore in total this can lead to a lot of memory being used.

**What I think is happening**

My assumption is that only visible TableRows (probably with the exception of a few additional rows to improve scrolling speed) actually use memory.

**The questions:**

1. Has anybody else seen similar behaviour?
2. How to solve this issue?
3. Is this a bug in the JavaFX framework or a bug in using the TableView?

**The deps:**

- JDK 1.8.0_151
- JavaFX8

Comment: Can you provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to showcase the issue? Since I suppose your code is not open source I'd like you to reproduce the issue this way to improve answerability.

Comment: my crystal ball tells me .. ;) Basically, there's nothing wrong (that I know of) with rows in VirtualFlow. Columns might pose a problem, as they are not (yet) virtualized, though it's more on performance than on memory. Do you have any custom rows/columns/cells/headers that might prevent gc? Anyway, there is no way around profiling your particular context extensively, not much we can do from here.